# GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( generation_expr ) STORED using gen_random_uuid

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table, generated-columns

Looking to create a table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable (
    id UUID  GENERATED ALWAYS AS gen_random_uuid() STORED,
    org uuid NOT NULL,
    name text,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    UNIQUE(name, org)
)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "gen_random_uuid"
LINE 2:     id UUID  GENERATED ALWAYS AS gen_random_uuid() STORED
```

Postgres docs [here(generated columns)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) and [here (table creation)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) say this should be possible:

> GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( generation_expr ) STORED
> This clause creates the column as a generated column. The column cannot be written to, and when read the result of the specified expression will be returned.
>
> The keyword STORED is required to signify that the column will be
> computed on write and will be stored on disk.
>
> The generation expression can refer to other columns in the table, but
> not other generated columns. Any functions and operators used must be
> immutable. References to other tables are not allowed.

What am I missing? Is gen_random_uuid not a generation expression? It seems to fit all of the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parentheses around the `generation_expr`. But that is only a syntactical problem, and you won't be able to use a generated column for that. Read a little further in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) you linked to, and you will find:

> - The generation expression can only use immutable functions and cannot use subqueries or reference anything other than the current row in any way.

Now `gen_random_uuid()` certainly is no `IMMUTABLE` function.

You have two options:

- use a column `DEFAULT` clause
- use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger if you don't want the user to be able to override the column `DEFAULT`

Comment: An extension to `identity` columns would be useful for a case like this. Something along the lines of `generated always as identity using (...)`  to use a different "generator" than a sequence.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There is the danger of colliding with the SQL standard and its possible future extensions.